# Python Pandas: regravando pd.read_table() com os comentários originais

Tags: python, pandas

Possuo um arquivo separado por tab no qual as primeiras linhas são comentários designados com '#'. Eu uso o seguinte código para puxar o arquivo sem os comentários...
O arquivo é algo como:

```
#comentario
#comentario
#comentario
#comentario
#comentario
Header1 Header2 Header3
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

E então eu uso o código abaixo para carrega-lo sem os comentários...

```
import pandas as pd
file_in = pd.read_table('arquivo.tsv', comment='#')
```

Desta forma:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Após isso que realizo algumas alterações na coluna Header1 com base nas informações de outro arquivo, e reescrevo o arquivo `file_in`:

```
file_in.to_csv('arquivo.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

A questão aqui é que eu gostaria que os comentários voltassem como no original, mas o arquivo salvado começa com o Header e não mais com os comentários!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que os comentários estão sendo simplesmente ignorados na leitura. O Pandas não representa os comentários internamente porque isso é algo específico desse formato de armazenamento (isto é, do CSV; se você salvar a tabela em uma base SQL, por exemplo, não existem "comentários"). Por isso o máximo que dá pra fazer é pedir para a função de leitura ignorar as linhas com o caractere de comentário.

Se você quer manter os comentários, eu sugiro lê-los junto com a tabela (em um trecho de código distinto), armazenar em uma lista, e depois gravá-los antes de fazer a gravação da tabela.

Eis um exemplo de código:

```
import pandas as pd

commentChar = '#'

# Primeiro, lê os comentários do arquivo original
comments = []
with open('arquivo.tsv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0] == commentChar:
            comments.append(line)

# Agora, lê a tabela ignorando os comentários
file_in = pd.read_table('arquivo.tsv', comment=commentChar)

# Abre o arquivo de destino para escrita, grava os comentários antes
# e só depois grava a tabela (note que ao invés de receber o nome do arquivo,
# a chamada de to_csv recebe o handler do arquivo aberto, já posicionado onde
# deve começar a gravação).

with open('arquivo.csv', 'w') as f:
    for comment in comments:
        f.write(comment)

    file_in.to_csv(f, index=False, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Entendi Luiz Vieira! Neste caso tudo o que eu quiser realizar de alterações no meu arquivo `file_in` eu realizo entre `file_in = pd.read_table('arquivo.tsv', comment=commentChar)
` e `with open('arquivo.csv', 'w') as f:
    for comment in comments:
        f.write(comment)`

Comment: Não, não. O `with open('arquivo.csv', 'w')` abre o arquivo para gravação, então somente **depois** dessa linha é que você pode gravar qualquer coisa (e, claro, enquanto dentro da estrutura do `with`).